# How to limit the number of truth values in cnf format file?

Tags: sat

I have tried using minisat+, and now I am using cryptominisat, they support **opb** format and **cnf** format respectively. In the opb file, I can use **x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 2** to represent two truth values out of four unknowns. How do I convert this constraint into a cnf file representation?

Simply speaking I want to be able to make the following constraints in the cnf file: **x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 2**, which shows that only two of the 4 unknowns are true, I don't know how to build the constraint clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the cryptominisat developers, this is called, cardinality constraint, and cryptominisat doesn't support this natively, but it is possible to convert this constraint to cnf format via [pblib](https://github.com/master-keying/pblib).